# How to use BindingSource, datagridView and navigating buttons together

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview, datasource

is there any chance to make the navigating buttons operate on the whole database while the datagrid would show only the filtered results? I mean, I have  a datagridview and some textboxes corresponding to the columns. When I filter my data, the datagridview gets filled and the textboxes showing the data of the first row. When i move through the datagridview to the next row, the values in the textboxes change correspondingly. Now, I would like to filter first, then to click on a datagrid row. Afterwards,( because i don't need the filtered results any more) i would like just to drop them and to navigate just through common buttons on the whole unfiltered data. For example:

1. Filter for all Names starting with "S",
2. DoubleClick on the Row,
3. Navigate from this entry with the buttons, not
   only on the names starting with "S", but to the next or previous
   entry in the database.

I know how to navigate using BindingSource.MovePrevious() or MoveNext(), but as long as I use the same bindingSource i navigate through the same filtered set of data.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean filter and display only names starting with "s"?

Comment: Do you want to clear the filter upon the doubleclick? Using two BindingSources is often a good solution, IMO. You will have to make clearer to us what should happaen..